# Javascript modal dialog box with yes, yes to all

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 2. I know it is more of logic related. But checking if there is any open source dialog box for my scenario.

In my use case I am importing csv file and verify data. During the import I have to compare if the data is already there in my system or not. Suppose out of 50 records from csv if 3 records already existing in my table. I need to capture those 3 and display a warning dialog with record exists and do you want to overwrite information and prompt "Yes" "Yes to All"  "No" "No to All" buttons. If the user clicks on Yes show the second record out of 3 and go on.

Any help appreciated.

Kiran

Comment: Using the modal dialog API provided by a library like ng-bootstrap, https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home, is the way to go.

Comment: another option is https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal